# Open UIViewController inside UITabbar from SideMenu

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, swift4

My app has UITabBarController and SideMenu for which I am using SWReavealController, so in this Sidemenu there is a list of same UIViewControllers which are in Tabbar, so if I click on one of an item from Sidemenu I want that it should open inside Tabbar. 
I tried doing this

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
```

on click of an item of Sidemenu but it doesn't work, I want a solution for it and please refer to image what I want to achieve in case you don't understand the question.
[image]

So currently my code on select of side menu item is

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.revealViewController().revealToggle(animated: true)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "faeFromSideMenuSegue", sender: self)

}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing right now please share some code.

Comment: @sanjaykmwt check my edited question now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue because of you are directly opening `TabbarVC2` from side menu that will create a new instance outside `UITabbar`.

To overcome this issue.

- Create a `protocol` to trigger the actions for `Tabbar` selections
- Close the `SideMenu` when click on SideMenu's `TableViewCell`
- Along with that call `delegate` functions that you created to trigger Tabbar actions

Hope this will help you

Comment: can you tell me method implementation for the action of tabbar because this thing tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2 doesn't work

Comment: you have to create a protocal for your tabbar controller and call that from SideMenuView Controller using delegate. and make sure that delegate call correctly

Comment: I did what you told, in the Implementation of this method I am selecting the respected index of Tabbar controller (for eg: tabbar.selectedIndex = 2), when I am putting this in viewDidLoad of Tabbar class it is selecting the particular index, but when I am calling from side menu it is not changing its index